# Android screen not loading in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I launch Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat(Android 7.1-API 25), The avd player launches but the screen displaying Android keeps showing. It dosent load to the android main page.

screenshot

[image: android avd screenshot]

Comment: You should use genymotion for run the app. it is best virtual device and run smoothly.

Comment: try pixel device once

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it might take a long time to boot during the first time.So wait until it turns on or shows some error.

Secondly delete the virtual device and than install new device from ADV manager.(it will be good to install new device with latest API version and 86x)